# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola chicos tengo un problema con un controlador en PHP pues me sale

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\api-descargar-cfdi-main\api-descargar-cfdi-main\app\Http\Controllers\api\v1\MakeQueryController.php:20
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\api-descargar-cfdi-main\api-descargar-cfdi-main\app\Http\Controllers\api\v1\MakeQueryController.php on line 20

Tengo el código de esta manera

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\api\v1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MakeQueryController extends Controller
{}
```

He estado buscando información y probado lo que he encontrado y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que es en ese código donde se lanza la excepción? Agrega todo el trazo del error

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta y agregué todo lo que me devuelve el debug

Comment: Te dice que el error está en la línea 20 del `MakeQueryController` > `MakeQueryController.php:20`. ¿Qué tienes en la línea 20?

Comment: En esa linea tengo class MakeQueryController extends Controller

Comment: Emm... disculpa, pero en el código que muestras ese código no parece estar más que en la línea 7 u 8. Agrega a la pregunta todo lo que tengas en ese archivo, o por lo menos hasta la línea 30